# Issue in communicating with android using Ubidots

Tags: android, iot

I enter the two complile lines of code from Ubidots web services. Afterwards I sync the gradle files with the project and attempted to run the program. But an error pops up regarding the App Compact Activity ? The entire android application is functioning.

```
build.gradle {

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.mobileapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
        compile 'com.ubidots:ubidots-java:1.6.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
}
```

Comment: explain your issue clearly

Comment: I think you need to add appcompat v7 dependency to your project.